# Packaging Selenium in py2exe

Tags: python, selenium, py2exe

I am building a simple python app (myFile.py), using Python 3.4 with Selenium v2.44 (firefox web driver) and PyQt4 and want to distribute it. However, I am running into some problems including the `webdriver.xpi` and `webdriver_prefs.json` into the `library.zip` in my dist file.

Searching has given me plenty of results of people with the same problem, however, none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me.

My current **setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


wd_path = 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver'
required_data_files = [('selenium/webdriver/firefox',
                    ['%s\\firefox\\webdriver.xpi'%wd_path, '%s\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'%wd_path])]

setup(
    windows= {"myFile.py"},
    data_files = required_data_files,
    options = {
           "py2exe":{
                    "skip_archive": True,
                    "unbuffered": True,
                    "includes":["sip", "PyQt4"],
                    'optimize': 2
                    }
           },
    requires=['selenium'],
)
```

However, when the dist is created, I still have a `library.zip` that I can't manually add `webdriver.xpi` and `webdriver_prefs.json` too, additionally, it just creates a directory called selenium in the dist folder, it does not add it to the library. I was under the impression the `-skip_archive` option would NOT create a `.zip` file, but one is being created regardless.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Ryan

Comment: I found a workaround that I am not completely satisfied with, using PhantomJS and throwing the phantomJS.exe into the same directory as the created py2exe .exe, I got my program to perform as expected. This solution doesn't really answer my question, but maybe it will help someone coming across a similar problem.